# Machine Account Password Process and

Tags: active-directory

Machine Account Password Process and the trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed.

Was trying to understand and looking for documents on Machine Account Password Process ?

the trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed, in which circumstances do we get this error ?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Can you please [edit] your question to clarify what programs you are using and give us a chronological breakdown of what you were doing?

Answer (score 0):

this happens sometimes when the computer is off for too long and the computer and server are out of sync. Generally the fix for this is to remove the client from the domain and then add it again. Before adding it again, make sure to go into the `Domain Users and Computers` console on the server and remove the entry for that PC if it still exists.